# OpenCV Android image path

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am new to android platform and I'm trying to create an Android application for image processing... so I want to integrate openCV with it.

I have created an event processImage which is supposed to call a simple openCV library and perform Gaussian smoothing.

```
 public void processImage(View v) {



try
{
IplImage image = cvLoadImage("IMG/res.jpg");
System.out.println(image.depth());//null pointer exception here

 if (image != null) 
 {
    cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 10);
    cvSaveImage("IMG/res.jpg", image);
    cvReleaseImage(image);
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

   ImageView portrait = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc);
}
```

Obviously, my intent is to display and do other stuff with res.jpg, once this is done.

But I'm seeing a null pointer exception while accessing the image.
Evidently, Android doesn't allow us to use relative/absolute path like we do in standalone applications.

Question is... how do I get to accessing this image.

I guess the solution must be quite simple.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
/sdcard/IMG/res.jpeg
```

for writing to sd-card.
And you need to set the permission for sd-card write on AndroidManifest.xml
 like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: It is better to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of the hardcoded path to the sdcard.

Comment: That means to access an image lying static in my 'res' directory, I have to first export it to my SD card and then reload it using openCV? Sounds a bit roundabout (however, if that is the only option left... I will stop exploring :{ ). Ain't there a more direct way to do that?